# Failed to Convert Datetime

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am sorry to ask, but I tried a couple of days & failed to convert datetime in Python.

I have been trying to convert the 1st column (Date) into datetime format.
Then minus 7 hours & 30 minutes as a new column named as 'PDN date'.
Since there are bad data (e.g. string) in the 'Date' Column,
I used " errors='coerce' " to convert bad data into NAN

```
import datetime
Tonnage1["PDN Date"]=pd.to_datetime(Tonnage1["Date"], format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')+datetime.timedelta(hours=-7,minutes=-30)
Tonnage1.head()
```

Eventually, what i get is all NAT in 'PDN Date' column.
What can I do? :'(

**Appendix:**

Here is the entire script:

**get files in google drive:*

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount ('/content/drive')
```

**import everythings as usual:*

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
import openpyxl
```

**combine all files in google drive:*

```
li=[]
os.chdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Raw Data/')
allFiles=(glob.glob("*/*/*.xls"))

for file in allFiles:
  df=pd.read_excel(file,index_col=False)

  li.append(df)

Tonnage=pd.concat(li,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
```

*Eliminate unnecessary columns:*

```
Tonnage1=Tonnage.drop([  "Unnamed: 5","Unnamed: 6","Unnamed: 7","Unnamed: 8","Unnamed: 9","Unnamed: 10","Unnamed: 11","Unnamed: 12","Unnamed: 13","Unnamed: 14","Unnamed: 15","Unnamed: 16","Unnamed: 17"],axis=1)
```

**Rename headers*

```
Tonnage1 = Tonnage1.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'Date','Unnamed: 1':'formula','Unnamed: 2':'Customer','Unnamed: 3':'sortClass','Unnamed: 4':'weight'})
```

**Finally convert the date*

```
 Tonnage1["PDN Date"]=pd.to_datetime(Tonnage1["Date"], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')+datetime.timedelta(hours=-7,minutes=-30)
    Tonnage1.head()
```

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Comment: see also [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/10197418)

Comment: I tried to change $y to %Y but it resulted in all NAT.

Comment: @Valkyrie - also change `-` to `/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, change `%y` to `%Y` for match year in format `YYYY` and also `/` instead `-`:

```
Tonnage1["Date"]=pd.to_datetime(Tonnage1["Date"], 
                                format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',
                                errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I did it. Special thanks to jezrael. :)